# Java applications/IDE not opening (IntelliJ, Toolbox, NetBeans)

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am trying to install JetBrains toolbox, IntelliJ, and Pycharm so I can use them on my computer. When installing these they seem to install fine (no errors) but when I launch the applications I get a number of errors for classes not being found such as the ca certs and random bootstrap errors. I am not sure what the problem is but when talking with IntelliJ support they mentioned it was a Java Swift issue (not sure what this is) as it affected more than just JetBrains products. Does anyone have any advice for me to solve this issue?

System:

- Windows 10 (up to date)
- AMD CPU
- NVIDIA GPU

What I have tried:

- Reinstall all java
- reinstall windows and keeping files (remove all other apps)
- reinstall windows and delete all files (started fresh)

If there is any other info needed to help please let me know and I can get that as well.

Error from running .bat for IntelliJ (Updated 10/5):

```
2021-10-05 10:17:55,272 [     25]  ERROR -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - UI initialization failed
com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:264)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/java2d/pipe/PixelFillPipe
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/java2d/pipe/PixelFillPipe
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData.<clinit>(NullSurfaceData.java:66)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SurfaceData.initIDs(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SurfaceData.<clinit>(SurfaceData.java:120)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.initIDs(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.<clinit>(WToolkit.java:130)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$21(StartupUtil.java:434)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        ... 6 more
2021-10-05 10:17:55,280 [     33]  ERROR -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2  Build #IU-212.5284.40
2021-10-05 10:17:55,286 [     39]  ERROR -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2021-10-05 10:17:55,286 [     39]  ERROR -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10
Exception in thread "JobScheduler FJ pool 4/31" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/ServiceConfigurationError
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory$PlatformMBeanFinder.lambda$static$0(ManagementFactory.java:926)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:430)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory$PlatformMBeanFinder.<clinit>(ManagementFactory.java:922)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:684)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:364)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.logEssentialInfoAboutIde(StartupUtil.java:862)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$8(StartupUtil.java:225)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)

!bootstrap.error.title.start.failed!
!bootstrap.error.message.internal.error.please.refer.to.0!https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors!

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:264)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/java2d/pipe/PixelFillPipe
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/java2d/pipe/PixelFillPipe
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData.<clinit>(NullSurfaceData.java:66)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SurfaceData.initIDs(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SurfaceData.<clinit>(SurfaceData.java:120)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.initIDs(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.<clinit>(WToolkit.java:130)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$21(StartupUtil.java:434)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        ... 6 more

-----
!bootstrap.error.message.jre.details!11.0.12+7-b1504.28 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\jbr!

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.<clinit>(RepaintManager.java:243)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4843)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3409)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setEditable(JTextComponent.java:1818)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:323)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:198)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:87)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:264)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:219)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.logAndExit(StartupAbortedException.java:88)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:264)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
2021-10-05 10:17:55,366 [    119]  ERROR - j.openapi.util.ShutDownTracker - class com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory tried to access method 'void com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap.<init>(int, float, com.intellij.util.containers.HashingStrategy)' (com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory and com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap are in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @7225790e)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory tried to access method 'void com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap.<init>(int, float, com.intellij.util.containers.HashingStrategy)' (com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory and com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap are in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @7225790e)
        at com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory.createWeakMap(CollectionFactory.java:54)
        at com.intellij.util.containers.CollectionFactory.createWeakIdentityMap(CollectionFactory.java:81)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.<init>(ObjectTree.java:29)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.<clinit>(Disposer.java:23)
        at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.dispose(SocketLock.java:106)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$lockSystemDirs$26(StartupUtil.java:767)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.ShutDownTracker.run(ShutDownTracker.java:46)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021-10-05 10:17:55,366 [    119]  ERROR - j.openapi.util.ShutDownTracker - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2  Build #IU-212.5284.40
2021-10-05 10:17:55,367 [    120]  ERROR - j.openapi.util.ShutDownTracker - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2021-10-05 10:17:55,368 [    121]  ERROR - j.openapi.util.ShutDownTracker - OS: Windows 10
```

Here is error from trying to launch JetBrains ToolBox app:

```
1.21.9712 19728 2021-10-02 14:56:39.849 WARN   DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 LoggingKt                 Failed to cleanup logs dir. java/util/Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Unknown Source)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.LoggingKt.cleanupLogsFolder(Logging.kt:35)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.entry.ToolboxEntry$startToolbox$2.invokeSuspend(toolbox-process-entry.kt:72)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
1.21.9712 19728 2021-10-02 14:56:39.896 INFO   main I18nKt                    UI Locale set to en
1.21.9712 19728 2021-10-02 14:56:39.921 ERROR  main CertificateManager        Failed to setup certificates: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getProviders(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.isConscryptPreferred(Platform.kt:194)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findJvmPlatform(Platform.kt:223)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform(Platform.kt:214)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(Platform.kt:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.kt:170)
    at okhttp3.tls.HandshakeCertificates$Builder.addPlatformTrustedCertificates(HandshakeCertificates.kt:142)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.CertificateManager.setupTrustManager(CertificateManager.kt:42)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.CertificateManager.<init>(CertificateManager.kt:25)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.SettingsManagerImpl.<init>(SettingsManager.kt:65)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.SettingsManagerImpl.<init>(SettingsManager.kt:36)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.interop.cef.NativeGUIProcessKt.createToolboxServices(NativeGUIProcess.kt:103)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.entry.ToolboxEntry.startToolbox(toolbox-process-entry.kt:76)
1.21.9712 19728 2021-10-02 14:56:39.921 ERROR  main ToolboxEntry              Failed to create services: java/lang/IllegalAccessError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/IllegalAccessError
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.CertificateManager.<init>(CertificateManager.kt:26)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.SettingsManagerImpl.<init>(SettingsManager.kt:65)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.SettingsManagerImpl.<init>(SettingsManager.kt:36)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.interop.cef.NativeGUIProcessKt.createToolboxServices(NativeGUIProcess.kt:103)
    at com.jetbrains.toolbox.entry.ToolboxEntry.startToolbox(toolbox-process-entry.kt:76)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the errors you are getting? Please post them as text and not as screen captures (i.e. images)

Comment: I had a number of issues with a certain updated version of Intellij and they eventually patched it, but running the .bat file from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Intellij IDEA ...\bin\idea.bat seemed to force it to launch. I could still see the errors poppin on cmd prompt, but the IDEA ran just fine. See if that works for you.

Comment: I added a couple of logs to this. I also tried launching from cmd using the .bat file and still got an error.

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME, or JAVA_BASE env vars set? Try to unset them and reboot.

Comment: I removed those out of the Path and also deleted the vars. When launching now I get ```Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.```

Comment: Updated Java and did a fresh install again and I am now able to open Netbeans but still have issues with IntelliJ (opened a new ticket with Jet Brains ass well). I have updated the IntelliJ logs above with most recent error when running .bat file.